# Facing issues using Keras np_utils.to_categorical

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I'm trying to solve a multi class classification problem and want to one hot encode the target variable. The problem is my target variable ranges from (1-5) and from the Keras documentation looks like, the target variable needs to range from 0 - num_classes.

I tried to use something like this

`Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(testY - 1, 5)`

After using this, in the prediction phase, there is no 5th target variable in the output for test set.There are only 4 target variables in the predicted data.
I'm thinking maybe the above operation has completely gotten rid of one cell from all rows and that's why the 5th target variable is missing.

Is there a different approach to this problem?

```
reviews_df.overall.value_counts()
```

Target Variable and their counts

```
4.0    10688 

3.0     9510

5.0     5975

2.0     3531

1.0      632

Name: overall, dtype: int64
```

After prediction.

```
array([[   1,   31],
       [   2, 2015],
       [   3, 3455],
       [   4,  567]])
```

Comment: do `Y_test = Y_test - 1` to make it form (0,4) then predict.  final prediction will predict +1

Comment: There is not much to say without code, classes go from index 0 to index num_classes - 1

Comment: @Pygirl I thought of that initially, to change the label from 0-4 instead of 1-5. But this is something like a Hackathon, where the Accuracy/ F1 is calculated based on the y_test submitted .So it will not be helpful here.

Comment: Actually that's how you do it. Even if you use label encoder you will do inverse of that while submitting the final prediction. If you convert all the labels to 0-4 then your prediction will be also from 0-4. While submitting the final prediction you will increment them by 1.